# Appending csv files in Azure datalake

Tags: powershell, azure, csv, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake

I have couple of 50GB+ csv files in azure datalake store saved under partitioned folders like -

```
source/table/partition1/file1.csv
source/table/partition2/file2.csv
...
source/table/partitionN/fileN.csv
```

Files have same structure.I want to merge/append all these files together using Azure Powershell commands and produce one large file in new location without harming the original files.

I tried following command -

```
Join-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName "DatalakeStoreName" 
-Paths "source/table/partition1/file1.csv",
"source/table/partition2/file2.csv" 
-Destination "/Merged/table/final.csv"
```

But this destroyed the original files and just created new final.csv
I am aware that, there is Azure Data factory available but it requires multiple code objects to be deployed and I am dealing with 7000+ feeds like this, so ideally I would like to run this merging activity via one powershell script.

Does any one know any efficient and different solution to this problem which keeps original files intact?

Comment: You could just create a copy of each first, then perform the join back to the original or an other destination? Alternatively you could use Azure Data Lake Analytics to treat the source files as a table and perform your querying over that to generate new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a U-SQL script defined right in Powershell. Just make sure you also have an Azure Data Lake Analytics account. A sample PowerShell script with the U-SQL script in line:

```
#You can also save the script locally on a file and use -ScriptPath instead of -Script
$usqlScript = @"
    @extract  = 
    SELECT 
        column1 string,
        column2 int,
        #... list all columns and data types
        columnN string,
        partition string,
        fileNumber int
    FROM source/table/{partition}/file{fileNumber}.csv

    OUTPUT @extract
        TO "combinedFiles.csv"
        USING Outputters.Csv();
"@

$adla = "DataLakeAnalyticsAccountName"
Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob -AccountName $adla -Script $usqlScript -Name "JobName"
```

The fileset source/table/{partition}/file{fileNumber}.csv will extract every file who's path matches that pattern, and save the wildcards {partition} and {fileNumber} as columns as well so you don't have to lose that information when consolidating your data. And your original files will remain untouched. Let me know if you have other questions!

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will check the viability of this in my setup. By any chance,Do we know performance of this U-SQL for large files , multiple 50gb+?

Comment: Performance will depend on the number of AU (Analytics Units) you are giving that job. For example, processing a 50GB CSV file will be partitioned into 50 vertices, that can be processed in parallel.

Comment: Does this solution work if the files have same columns, different order of columns?